# 403 error when trying to authenticate application with Twitter API

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, twitter

I'm trying to make Twitter API requests using [application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) but I'm getting a 403 error when sending the HTTP request to receive a bearer token. I think this could be due to my request not being formed properly, but I can't find the error (following guidelines linked above).

My code (Python 3.5) is as follows:

```
btwitter = twitterkey.encode('utf-8') #utf-8 encodes the key
twitterkey = b64encode(btwitter) #b64 encode key from "consumer:secret" to bytes 
twitterkey = bytes.decode(twitterkey) # decodes to string
url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token" 
data = "grant_type=client_credentials"
data = data.encode('utf-8')
headers = {'Authorization' : "Basic "+twitterkey+"", 'Content-Length' : '29','User-Agent':'myapp v1','Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}
method = 'POST'
request = urllib.request.Request(url,data,headers,method)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

I'm also not sure if I'm encoding the key properly. Following Twitter's documentation, I encode the string to bytes and then base64. I then convert the base64 back to a string so I can concatenate it to "Basic ", otherwise I get a TypeError.

When running this code, I get an error on the last line, shown below:

```
File "main.py", line 69, in <module>
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
...
File "<path>", line 589, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

EDIT:

After catching the error and printing, I get the following:

```
b'{"errors":[{"code":99,"message":"Unable to verify your credentials","label":"authenticity_token_error"}]}'
```

I've tried changing the headers (adding/removing Content-Length and User-Agent) but I'm getting the same error. Thanks.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the body of that error response looks like. I think I have an idea on what is going on here but I'd like to be certain first.

Comment: I added the output of error.fp.read(), but I'm not sure what to make of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the error - I was reading the key from a file and forgot to strip the newline character, so the key sent to the server was wrong.